# How to implement notification in laravel

Tags: laravel

everyone, I have a room booking website designed with laravel and now I want to notify the rooms owners when someone accept the room with his/her phone number and sent his/her phone number in the notification message.
If someone can help me please!

Comment: What you have done before?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the laravel nexmo package: https://github.com/Nexmo/nexmo-laravel
or you can use another notifications channel: https://laravel-notification-channels.com/